# What is proper way to store data in DateTimeField field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model Fixture

```
Class Fixture(models.Model):
     event_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I have piece of json data

```
for item in piece_json:
    event_timestamp = item["event_date"]
```

Where in `item["event_timestamp"]` the following data 1572567600

While i am trying to create object from this model

```
fixture = Fixture.objects.create(event_timestamp= event_timestamp)
```

I got the following error

```
match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

After this error i tried to wrap event_timestamp variable in built-in str() function

```
fixture = Fixture.objects.create(event_timestamp= str(event_timestamp))
```

After it i got error

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'1572651000' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think DateTimeField allowsyou to save Unix Timestamp.

What I can suggest you do is:

```
import datetime
fixture = Fixture.objects.create(event_timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(event_timestamp))
```